# Error with WCF client when using reference types

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am using a WCF driven silverlight application. The web services use reference types such as StringBuilder. However, while passing a StringBuilder or a DateTime object to & from service, the state of the object gets lost.
Is it not possible to update the state of the parameter/return type passed through a web service, if so, then what am I missing ?

I have verified my application, and my code is working fine otherwise (eg, if I use string or any other primitive types for updation via WCF service)

```
myObj //[myObj Is-A StringBuilder / Has-A StringBuilder, or any other 'reference' object type]

referenceObj.MethodAsync(myObj); // pass on to server-ignoring the values for now


server end  : no ref/out and Simple assignment/append of Value of/inside the object. Object state is updated.

//receive in the delegate
.. MethodCompletedEventArgs e){
myObj = e.Result;   // Expect here,the updated value
```

Answer (score 2):

WCF is not remoting. It's only used to transport information back and forth.

**Update**

You are still thinking that WCF is a drop in replacement to remoting.

Reference types are not transfered with their references as they did in .NET Remoting. They are treated as value types. The object received from the server is NOT the same object as the one existing in the server.

Hence, changing the object client side will not change it server side. You need to send it back and update the server-side object manually.

Comment: that's true, but the transportation in my case only happens over primitive variables

Comment: StringBuilder isn't a primitive. I had never had problems with primitives or my own object structures.

Comment: No, it is not the case. I understand WCF uses underlying WS-* and RESTful web services standards. I was updating the server-side object values correctly. Its just that the values are just not getting passed on the client end. While using axis2 library, there is no such problem.

Comment: @Sumit IMO you really haven't given much context for us to try to understand the scenario here...

Answer (score 1):

When passing over a service boundary, the data is essentially copied. Changes made at the other end are entirely lost, and do not go back to the caller. If you want the changes, then either:

- *return* those values in the response
- (in some cases) add `ref` to the parameter - the engine *may* use this to propagate the data back to the caller (note that in this case it will *swap* the object, not *merge* the changes)

(the first of the two is easier to reason about, and will work more consistently)

Comment: I tried passing the values, but was getting an empty, initialized value for eg, a stringbuilder array would have n number of objects initialized to their initial value {}, but there was no 'return' of values. BTW, I also tried ref & out and wrapping the response object without any success

Comment: @Sumit so... don't do that! It would never even occur to me to *try* passing a `StringBuilder` over such an API... `string` *sure*, but...?

Comment: So, it seems we cannot use any reference type in WCF ?

Comment: @Sumit no, that is not the case at all. Most types are classes (reference types) and work fine. `DateTime` (in your example) is *not* a reference type, but again: you need to ***return*** the value at some point.

Comment: @Sumit imagine: I write you a letter, photocopy it, and post the copy to you. You scribble on the letter. Do I expect to see the changes appear on my copy? No: I do not.

Comment: I understand your concern, but if i am having a null as a return type of my DataContract, I wouldn't have the return-objectEventArgs at the first place. All I am saying is that types like StringBuilder & DateTime are assigned a memory location, but their internal values (which are primitives) are not getting updated, and that's what has been baffling me.

Comment: @Sumit you've invoked a remote call, pushing the data over; I would have **absolutely no expectation** for those changes to come back. Maybe we're talking about different things - is there any code you can show to illustrate what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

When passing over a service boundary, the data is serialized (copied).  To ensure your class is serializable, add the [Serialize] keyword to the class.  If you are using an object that can't be serialized, the complier will issue an error.

As Marc said, WCF is not remoting.  Under COM, all data was passed by value, but to "help" out developers, it used underlying mechanism on the return to return the value, then create a reference to it under the covers.  Rather than help though, this caused a lot of problems that most developers could never figure out.  WCF changed all that, and everything is now passed by value.

HTH